# how to checkall Checkbox in datagrid Silverlight mvvm?

Tags: silverlight, entity-framework, mvvm

In my silverlight5 and MVVM project, I have one doubt.

I have one Datagrid control and I load some details of a customer.

My Datagrid structure is as follows.

```
[CheckBox] | CustomerName | CustomerAge
________________________________________
[CheckBox] | Raj          | 23
----------------------------------------
[CheckBox] | Ravi         | 24
----------------------------------------
[CheckBox] | Rajkumar     | 25
________________________________________


<sdk:DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Details}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem,Mode=TwoWay}" Name="DG">
<sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
  <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderStyle>
     <Style TargetType="sdk:DataGridColumnHeader">
        <Setter Property="Template">
          <Setter.Value>
             <ControlTemplate>
                <Grid>
                  <CheckBox VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                            Command="{Binding AllCheckedCommand}"/>
                </Grid>
             </ControlTemplate>
          </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
     </Style>
   </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderStyle>
   <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
   <DataTemplate>
           <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected,Mode=TwoWay}" Content="Select All" 
                     VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
   </DataTemplate>
   </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
   </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>

   <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Name" MinWidth="130" MaxWidth="180">
   <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
           <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name,Mode=TwoWay}" />
       </DataTemplate>
   </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
   </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>


   <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Age" MinWidth="130" MaxWidth="180">
   <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
           <TextBlock Text="{Binding Age,Mode=TwoWay}" />
       </DataTemplate>
   </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
   </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
 </sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
```

If i have checked the top header CheckBox means all the CheckBox also checked. how to establish this.

Note: Here (ItemsSource="{Binding Details}") Details is a class that contains the name and age.

How to achieve this..? please help me to do this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We sorted this out in WPF chatroom. It turns out that the Model being used in `DataContext` didn't have `IsSelected` property and hence the code wasn't running (or compiling).